# DataGridVIEW Refresh C# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Im Using a DataGridView loaded By SQL Connection, I want refresh the DataGridView but without move the DataGridView to the top or bottom. to update now I'm loading the DataGridView again with the data source by sql, how i refresh without move ?

Comment: Do you mean changing the scroll position?

Comment: yeah, i want the scroll position dont move when refrsh

Comment: Do you mean a DataGridView?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: It also sounds like you are doing it the hardest way possible.

Comment: My bad for the poor information

Answer (score 0):

Before you rebind the DataGridView, call `dgv.SuspendLayout` then store the current selected row, cell and/or keyvalue. Then rebind the control, restore the selected items and scroll them into view, then call `dgv.ResumeLayout`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The question is tagged `DataGrid` not `DataGridView`

Comment: @Plutonix OP has edited the post to reflect DataGridView.